# Start new activity on uncaughtException

Tags: android, exception

I know that there are many similiar questions but I don't understand why exactly my code not working. I try start new activity from exception handler by code like this

```
class CrashHandler private constructor(private val context: Context) :
    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private val defaultHandler: Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler =
        Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()

    companion object {
        fun instalHandler(context: Context) {
            if (!(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() is CrashHandler)) {
                Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(CrashHandler(context))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun uncaughtException(t: Thread?, e: Throwable?) {
        val intent = Intent(context, ExceptionActivity::class.java)
        (context as Activity).startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

but I obtain only black screen.

Comment: Why not use an existing framework for this, like [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your answer. I'm new in android development and I try understand all possible ways and all pitfalls.  In my case I try only open specific activity but don't publish report. ACRA and report publishing I think will be the next step of my studing. Sorry, for such newbie question.

Comment: It's more that what you are trying to do is difficult to get right, as the app is in an unknown and possibly unstable state at the time of the crash. The people behind ACRA (and commercial crash logging libraries) have spent a lot of time working out the ways to do work in response to a crash.